# Need assistance optimizing query performance

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have two queries that are basically the same:

***OLD "TRANSACTIONS" QUERY***

```
SELECT t.payment_method, t.amount, t.commission
FROM `transactions` t, `member_to_group` mtg, `member` m
WHERE mtg.`group_id`='37'
   AND t.`is_deleted`='No'
   AND t.`member_id`=mtg.`member_id`
   AND m.member_id=mtg.member_id
   AND m.`is_root`='No'
   AND t.`type` IN ('Payment','Credit')
```

***NEW "PAYMENTS" QUERY***

```
SELECT p.method, p.amount, p.commission
FROM `payments` p, `member_to_group` mtg, `member` m
WHERE mtg.`group_id`='37'
   AND p.`status`='Active'
   AND p.`member_id`=mtg.`member_id`
   AND m.member_id=mtg.member_id
   AND m.`is_root`='No'
```

The first from the "transactions" table, and the second from a newer table called "payments".  Basically we had one giant table for every transaction (payments, credits, charges, fees,etc) and it got out of hand because there were always a great deal of fields that weren't used for each type -- so we split the basic types up.

For some reason, despite the better organization of the newer table system (all in the same database, mind you), and the similarities between the queries, the older "transaction" query runs much faster. The "transaction" table returns the result in 0.004 seconds while the "payments" query takes 0.303.  In some areas on the web application (e.g. listings for multiple groups), this translates into 40 second page load times (as opposed to under 3).

Is there a single field (or multi-field) index I might want to use?  Can I further optimize the new query?

This is running on MySQL 5.0.92

**EDIT 1:** I currently have single-field indexes on "transactions" (transaction_id, member_id) and "payments" (id, member_id).  Unfortunately I only have access to PHPMYADMIN on this particular server and the EXPLAIN output isn't readily copyable.  That said, I can see a difference on the "transaction" query in that it says "using where;using index" on the mtg table whereas the "payment" transaction simply says "using where".

Comment: You asked if there are any indexes you should add; what indexes are currently on each table? How much data is in the Payments table compared to the Transactions table?

Comment: We don't know what indexes you have on those tables today. Can you post some `EXPLAIN` results? That usually tells where the problem is.

Comment: For the record, there is no such thing as a humble coder. :)

Comment: Also, remove all those unnecessary backticks to make your query easier to read. backticks are only required when a column/table has a name that is a reserved word (never a good idea anyway). mysql puts them in its schema query output because it's easier (and mysql is stupid)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all i would rewrite it as :

```
SELECT 
    payments.method, 
    payments.amount,
    payments.commission
FROM payments
    LEFT JOIN member_to_group ON payments.member_id = member_to_group.member_id 
    LEFT JOIN member ON member.member_id = member_to_group.member_id
WHERE member_to_group.group_id = '37'
    AND payments.status = 'Active'
    AND member.is_root = 'No'
```

Then, try to compare the both queries using **[EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html)** statement. This should show you where are the differences.

Next i would take a look at this line `WHERE member_to_group.group_id = '37'` and make sure that i compare the columns against `INT` value instead of `VARCHAR` .. with all the fitting indexes.

As for `payments.status` and `member.is_root` , both columns should be indexed (*AFAIK*, MySQL still does not support partial indexing).

I am assuming that that following columns are primary/foreign keys and indexed accordingly:

- `payments.member_id`
- `member_to_group.member_id`
- `member.member_id`

P.S. you could play around with order of `WHERE` statements , but i think that **should** be already handled by database's internal query optimization .. but who knows , it's mysql.

---

**update**

If the `EXPLAIN` says that you are not using indexes on `member_to_group` table, then you should check the indexes that both columns ( which are used in that query ): `group_id` and `member_id` .. at least one of them is *not indexed* in `member_to_group`.

Comment: Nice.  Is this functionally better or simply more legible?

Comment: @humble_coder , that query is just "cleaning up" of your existing one. It **should not** function better. Then again, i have not really explored how mysql handles multiple tables in the `FROM` statement.

Comment: @humble_coder You might wanna do some reading up on how to join tables.  Usually when you find tables joined the way you were doing it, the query was written 15 years ago.  Having said that, the performance technically shouldn't be any different between joining in the where clause or using join statements (although his query is slightly different than yours because he uses left joins).

Comment: @humble_coder That is, his query could potentially return more results than yours if there are rows on the left side of the joins that don't have no matches on the right side.

Comment: @BrandonMoore:  Yeah, the current code base is not quite 5 years old, but it was pulled from code that was even older -- soooooo, yup.  Although, admittedly, I'm not one for verbosity when it comes to SQL specifically.  *hides* =\

Comment: @BrandonMoore , well .. the `LEFT JOIN` was the safest bet, because there was no information about what is contained in tables, and i really don't know how `FROM table1, table2, table3` translates to a join .. for all i know it would be `FULL OUTER` =/

Comment: @tereško:  Still no good.  I tried your query as well as my query, with and without the new indexes.  Your query is actually about .004 slower.  I still appreciate the input though.

Comment: @tereško:  Yeah, the main difference between the two EXPLAINs is the "transactions" query makes use of an index on "member_to_group", but for some reason when I run the "payments" query, it doesn't.  I have no idea why.  Clearly I'm missing something, but I don't know what.  All table types are the same, there doesn't seem to be anything special about the indexes or the field types themselves.  The field lengths are all the same.  I'm genuinely lost.

Comment: @tereško: Your query does show the use of an index on "member_to_group", however it's positioned last in the explanation and doesn't seem to have a positive effect.  Still, progress I suppose.

Comment: is there an index on mtg.group_id?

Comment: @humble_coder , well .. you are using two columns from that table: `group_id` and `member_id` .. one of them is not indexed in `member_to_group`.

Comment: @tereško: OMG! I was completely misreading the "member_to_group" idxs.  There was only one created as a multi-field PRIMARY.  I simply created  two separate ones and BAM! it went from .303 to .0016.  Thank you sir!  Please add your full explanation to your main post.  I'd still like to know why the "transactions" query ran faster by default, but at this point I'm just happy to have this fixed.

Comment: @tereško His code is equivalent to an inner join.  If I remember correctly, the syntax to do outer joins using that method is *= and =*.  In sql server you'd get an error message if you tried to use the star syntax for joins and tell you to lower the compatibility level if you want to use it.  Not sure how MySql would react.

Comment: Oh, the comment removed my stars.  There is supposed to be a star before the first '=' sign and a star after the second one.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, you can add indexes on `JOIN` fields and `WHERE` clause fields and `ORDER BY` fields to improve performance.
Note that this will affect insert performance when inserting records, but as long as this doesnt matter then you should be fine.

So, to answer your question, you could add indexes on:

```
mtg.group_id
p.status
p.member_id
mtg.member_id
m.member_id
m.isroot
```

**EDIT**

Assuming the ID fields are already primary key fields and as such will already have indexes on them.

Also it appears your `is_root` and `status` are varchar fields where it would be better if they were a tinyint(1) and integer respectively.
If you need to get the text representation out you can create a separate table mapping these values

Comment: Individual indexes or specific combinations?

Comment: Individual, comination indexes are explained here: http://askville.amazon.com/MYSQL-composite-index-fields-separately/AnswerViewer.do?requestId=718314  which i dont think will help your case

Comment: Also look at teresco's answer - this is the better way to write your query

Answer (score 0):

What indexes do you have on the payments table?  Consider adding an index that with the member_id and the status columns.